# Unable to Edit Text On Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]Hi, I've just started using Visual Studio Code as my primary code editor and it was working fine for the past couple days, although today when I opened it and tried to edit a file I couldn't. Whenever I tried to write anything the file wouldn't get those words and the cursor would just jump between points every time I clicked a key. I was wondering what is causing this and how can I fix it?

And just an additional point, whenever I go and click on a word, rather than giving me a normal typing cursor I'm getting a cursor which you primarily see in terminal windows where it's a rectangular box

Comment: you have an `Analyzing` in the status bar, maybe that takes a lot of CPU resources, view the TaskManager

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows 45k+ problems. You have quite possibly deleted something important. Check if the following command works in the terminal.

```
flutter clean
```